# Keep screen on during android game without user interaction

Tags: android, mobile, libgdx

I'm using Libgdx for my android game. The game runs fine, but it will automatically pause while running if there is no interaction from the user. How can I avoid the game pause?

My main class impelments `AndroidApplication` and my game class implements `ApplicationListener`.

Answer (score 8):

While JRowan's answer is good for general Android applications, and can be used with Libgdx, you can also use the Libgdx support for acquiring the wakelock.  See [`useWakelock`](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/backends/android/AndroidApplicationConfiguration.html#useWakelock) in [`AndroidApplicationConfiguration`](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/backends/gdx-backend-android/src/com/badlogic/gdx/backends/android/AndroidApplicationConfiguration.java).  Libgdx will keep track of the wakelock for you.  You still need the appropriate permissions in your manifest, though.

Specifically, in your class that extends `AndroidApplication`:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    AndroidApplicationConfiguration cfg = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();
    cfg.useWakelock = true;

    initialize(new MyGdxGame(), cfg);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    wakeLock = powerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK, "GLGame");
wakeLock.acquire();
```

and you have to put the permission wakelock in your manifest

and when your done with the wakeLock release it

```
wakeLock.release();
```

or

A safer approach is to use setKeepScreenOn() or android:keepScreenOn for some View in the activity. You do not need the WAKE_LOCK permission, and you cannot readily screw it up by failing to release it. As soon as the keep-screen-on View is no longer in the foreground, device behavior returns to normal.

Comment: don't forget `wakeLock.release();` when you are done with it (i.e. when your app is stopped.)

Comment: A safer approach is to use `setKeepScreenOn()` or `android:keepScreenOn` for some `View` in the activity. You do not need the `WAKE_LOCK` permission, and you cannot readily screw it up by failing to release it. As soon as the keep-screen-on `View` is no longer in the foreground, device behavior returns to normal.

Answer (score 0):

Better and easier way,no need to worry about releasing anythinng

Just copy this code in AndroidLauncher.java file

> @Override protected void createWakeLock(boolean use) { use=true;
>   super.createWakeLock(use); }

for more see[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40160469/how-to-awake-screen-while-game-play-in-libgdx/41466524#41466524)