# How to awake screen while game play in libgdx?

Tags: libgdx

I am creating an game using accelerometer  in libgdx and while playing the game, it sleeps after some, i need awake this untill game-play. i got this in some forums

```
 getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
```

which work for android app,but don't how to do that in libgdx, it is unrecognizable by compiler.any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Use `config.useWakelock = true` in the AndroidLauncher class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Best and easiest way to do that  is

1. Go to the android folder of your project in android studio
2. then locate AndroidLauncher.java in src sub-folder
3. then copy and paste code below

   > @Override     protected void createWakeLock(boolean use) {        use=true;
   >         super.createWakeLock(use);  }

   after adding code whole file will look like this

   > public class AndroidLauncher extends AndroidApplication {     @Override
   >     protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   >         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   >         AndroidApplicationConfiguration config = new
   >   AndroidApplicationConfiguration();        initialize(new MyBomber(),
   >   config);
   >
   > }
   >
   > @Override   protected void createWakeLock(boolean use) {        use=true;
   >         super.createWakeLock(use);  } }

Answer (score 3):

`onCreate` method of AndoridLauncher create a configuration object and set `useWakelock=true`

```
AndroidApplicationConfiguration config = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();
config.useWakelock=true;

initialize(new MyGdxGame(), config);
```